# letterSpacing Does not work

Tags: react-native, styles

hi guys i'm on a problem now, I have given spacing for my Text tag but in fact it doesn't show any spacing on the screen,

i'm giving the code below

```
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    letterSpacing:2,
    fontSize:NormalizeSize.normalize(16,true),
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
```

Comment: try with letter-spacing:2px;

Comment: is that css ? actually it does not work

Comment: [This](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3233) and [this](https://www.devmynd.com/blog/cross-platform-letter-spacing-react-native/) might help you and give you some idea.

Comment: ok let me check this and get back

Comment: sorry im a bit late. @RaviRupareliya yeah it gave me absolutely some help but unfortunately it didnt work well because the alignment goes wrong while implementing due to the padding it gives. anyway thanks!